# Why do genitals feel frozen when freefalling?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, human-genetics

I don't want to add much more about that. Since childhood I noticed a chilling effect, even when doing rollercoaster-type activities.

Comment: Is there evidence that what you are describing is a general phenomenon?

Answer (score 3):

Probably because the blood would be forced, physically, that is, by inertia to move upwards during free-fall, thus causing the genital's blood supply to become obstructed thus reducing their temperature and thus leading to the sensation of them being frozen as you described. Plus you might feel cooler all over your body due to the air flow against it and since your genitals wouldn't be as biologically favoured when your body's survival instincts for low-temperature environments kicks in you're body would probably reduce the blood flow to your genitals and other extremities favouring your vital organs such as your heart, lungs, brain, etc. with a greater blood supply to keep them warm and working.

Comment: If it were blood flow, wouldn't your feet be cold as well?

Comment: Perhaps but perhaps as part of the person in question's biology the genitals are for some reason more prone to decreased blood flow. Different people have slightly different biologies and seeing  how from what I can tell this isn't a super common occurance in people this theory seems quite valid.

Comment: If it's not a general phenomenon, then I think the question is too narrow (i.e., applicable to only one person).

Comment: I kind of think you shouldn't be discussing that with me but rather with the asker under the question itself seeing how its more applicable to him/her. Put it to him/her that if they cannot find someone who experiences this too under those circumstances the question will be closed.

Comment: i think its all the ennervation in the region - they are quite sensitive compared to other ... regions